# Mosaic function adding non-desired value to dataset in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mosaic, arcgis-10.7

I am working with a land cover dataset, which is a 30m-grid multi-band dataset, with each band representing the data from a different year (ABoVE data, GeoTiff file). For the convenience, I used the mosaic function to merge my data layers. My dataset has this value range from 1 to 15 (15 groups), representing 15 different land cover functional groups. But it seems the mosaic function added a "value 0" into my dataset, so the value range of my mosaic raster has become 0 to 15 (16 groups).

This problem also occurred in my another mosaic dataset (MODIS data, HDF4 format, but after the mosaic function the output format was set to .tif), which has the value range from 1 to 17. An 0 value has also been added to the dataset.

I found it became very confusing when I am trying to do reclassification as the values does not match to the original dataset and the user manual.

Why does this problem occur, and how can I fix this?